# Why we must load textures AFTER creating windows in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

In my situation,

```
glutInitWindowSize(w_walker*8, h_walker);
glutCreateWindow("walker");
loadTexture("./fighter512.png");
```

worked, but

```
loadTexture("./fighter512.png");
glutInitWindowSize(w_walker*8, h_walker);
glutCreateWindow("walker");
```

did not. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, with some drivers/OpenGL implementations, the act of creating the window has the side effect of determining where the memory for textures, off-screen buffers and the window itself will actually live and consequently how big it will be too.

Without creating the window (or more precisely the rendering context) it's hard (i.e. impossible) to determine where to put the texture once loaded.

Comment: I'd rather say that without the OpenGL context that is created by glut, OpenGL is uninitalized and not active at all, and hence, cannot load textures. See http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context

Comment: It's about having a OpenGL context, not about windows and sizes.

Comment: ... but the location of the window determines which video driver gets used for the OpenGL context.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Technically it's not neccesary to tie the OpenGL context to a certain video device. The devices of course determine what extensions and features are available. But there's nothing that would prevent creation of an OpenGL context that spans multiple devices, even from different makers. The Windows way of providing OpenGL access is suboptimal, but just look at X11/GLX + DMX + Chromium, which provides accelerated OpenGL spanning not only multiple GPUs but multiple _machines_!

Comment: @datenwolf: That's necessarily not very accelerated.  This question is about loading textures, so let's focus on those... into which video device is the texture loaded?  All of them?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: How do you conclude it's not accelerated? OpenGL is very, very abstract. And especially modern techniques like Buffer Objects don't requires direct access anymore. I'm currently developing a demo based on a 8 bit AVR microcontroller that shows a full utilization of a OpenGL-3 capable GPU through X11/GLX.

Comment: @datenwolf: Mind telling me how data gets transferred between a geometry shader and a pixel shader on a different GPU (or a different computer, if you prefer)?  For full acceleration, everything has to happen internal to the GPU and its on-board high-bandwidth GDRAM.  Even data transfer to/from the CPU is minimized (this is how your AVR isn't badly bottlenecking your demo).  That just isn't possible unless the texture is allocated in the GDRAM of the GPU that needs it.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: OpenGL employs an abstract data model. Calling glTexImage, glBufferData, etc. don't copy the data directly to the GPU. A shadow copy will be kept. It is this shadow copy that allows to span an OpenGL context over multiple devices - however the OpenGL distributions shipped with the usual drivers don't implement that, as such is not mandated by the standard. However it is very well feasible and has been successfully implemented by Chromium.

Comment: @datenwolf: It's definitely possible to keep that state client-side, but doing so is less optimized than storing it in GDRAM.  (And you say "do not" and "will", then admit these are implementation details not guaranteed by the standard, which is rather contradictory.  Better would be "may not" and "could be kept").

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Transferring the results of vertex and fragment shader results is not neccesary. Spanning a OpenGL context over multiple GPUs will of course only yield HW acceleration as long as the common subset of available features is used. All GPUs would recieve the same data an commands, but each GPU's viewport is different. Primitives outside the clip region are culled very early on, fragment shaders gather, but don't scatter. If rendered to FBOs all GPUs will do the same. Chromium is not about incresing performance, one uses SLi or Crossfire for that.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: The OpenGL specification never talks about GDRAM, GPUs or any aspects of hardware implemetation. OpenGL is a very abstract API. Once you've successfully established an object, it must be warrented to be accessible and contain valid data at all times, that's all. Loading texture or buffer data does not neccessarily put things in the GDRAM. Object residency is as abstract either: OpenGL may report no object being resident at all, yet one can use it. Technically one can create much more texture objects than would fit into GDRAM and still use them all in a render pass.

Comment: @datenwolf: So you've finally answered my original question: "Yes, the texture is loaded into all of them."  BTW I realize the spec doesn't talk about hardware... but hardware is where acceleration happens.  Furthermore, shaders can create new vertexes and change their position, which could move them into the viewport of another device.  So it seems that all devices have to render the entire scene, at least up until rasterization begins.  Not very scalable, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL commands operate on a OpenGL context. GLUT creates a OpenGL context only after a window has been created. With PBuffers one can have a OpenGL context without a window. In X11/GLX creating PBuffers is straightforward; on Windows one has to create a dummy window first to access the OpenGL extensions used for creating a PBuffer, which requires an active OpenGL context beforehand. But once the PBuffer and a OpenGL context on it are created the dummy window is no longer needed.